# how to add new model in exist database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I add new model MVC in proper way? 
I have one model with `UsersContext`. I want to create another - `NewContext`.

Is the code below will work without any problems? And maybe there is a better solution to create model in existing database? What exacly mean `UsersContext` and `NewContext` in code?

```
public class NewContext : DbContext
{
    public NewContext ()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<test1> test1{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<test2> test2{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<test3> test3{ get; set; }

}
  (...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the code below will work without any problems?

Yes, this will work. The DbContext is used to group the entities you want to work with in your application. In fact you do not need a second context. You could have only one DbContext in which you add all your domain entities as `DbSet<T>` properties and then work with this context.

Comment: +1, thanks, but I have error - `The model backing the 'IdeasContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database` - why? What does it mean? and how to resolve it?

Comment: problem solved :) thanks again ! But can you show me solution with `DbSet<T>`? How it works etc.